# Swift code : Is there a way to make the alert view disappear automatically

Tags: swift

Is there a way to make the alert view disappear automatically.. after some seconds, without user action. Currently I have my code as follow, and it require user to press ok to disappear the alert dialog. I would like to show the alert and not have user intervention, and just have the alert disappear in few seconds. Thanks for any comments.

My code as below:

```
func showAlertController (message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delay anything with `dispatch_after`. For example, this would dismiss the alert view after 3 seconds.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                              Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

You can also use [@matt's awesome delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:) method